# Error: Could not determine kind of name for C.stdout when building example from C? Go? Cgo! article

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to build the following example from [C? Go? Cgo!](http://golang.org/doc/articles/c_go_cgo.html):

```
package print

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Print(s string) {
    cs := C.CString(s)
    C.fputs(cs, (*C.FILE)(C.stdout))
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
}
```

I'm running Go on Win7 64 and am using the 64 bit version of GCC from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/
Running this on Linux isn't an option.

The error I get is:

```
could not determine kind of name for C.stdout
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this message, and very few hits show up on Google.

Does anyone have ideas on what's causing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to access C.stdout on windows:

```
// Copyright 2009 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

package stdio

/*
#include <stdio.h>
// on mingw, stderr and stdout are defined as &_iob[FILENO]
// on netbsd, they are defined as &__sF[FILENO]
// and cgo doesn't recognize them, so write a function to get them,
// instead of depending on internals of libc implementation.
FILE *getStdout(void) { return stdout; }
FILE *getStderr(void) { return stderr; }
*/
import "C"

var Stdout = (*File)(C.getStdout())
var Stderr = (*File)(C.getStderr())
```

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/misc/cgo/stdio/stdio.go

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick. I wonder if cgo has trouble with #defines in general...

Answer (score 0):

In the cgo implementation there is a [method](http://golang.org/src/cmd/cgo/gcc.go#L315) to guess the types according to the output of gcc. It could be possible that you have set a different locale in your terminal and the guessing fails.

Try this:

```
LC_ALL=C go build
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I've tried setting the environment variables LANG, LC_TYPE, LC_MESSAGES, and LC_ALL. I still receive the error.